# Binding data from a PhoneApplicationPage's DataContext to a UserControl in that same page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, user-controls

This is driving me crazy as it should be so simple though I can't find the answer after hours of Google-ing and plowing trough forums, blogs and tutorials.

I have a UserControl in a page (classname : CheckListItemControl) and have set the DataContext of the page to "this" (to itself).  I gave this UserControl properties such as:

```
private string title;
public string Title{
   get{ return title; }
   set{ title = value; }
}
```

Now in that page I want to bind the value of property "ApplicationName" of the page to the Title-property of that UserControl, like so:

```
<src:CheckListItemControl x:Name="someControl" Title="{Binding ApplicationName}"/>
```

This doesn't work.  i can set normal text like this:

```
Title="Very cool wp7 app"
```

but not like this:

```
Title="{Binding ApplicationName}"
```

Running the app throws an exception.

I'm figuring this must have something to do with the scope of the DataContext but I don't know why or what.  A UserControl is just a control and if the other "normal" Controls in the page can bind to the DataContext, why can't the UserControl???

Help would be gladly appreciated, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Does applicationname supports binding...? It might be just that simple..

Comment: Yeah, it does.  I use it on other places in the PhoneApplicationPage with databinding without any problems, that's the strange thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems here.

First, to make the Title bindable, it needs to be a dependency property.

Second, if you have

```
DataContext = this;
```

in your usercontrol you probably want to remove it. As the DataContext will automatically flow down from the parent control to your usercontrol. Doing this will only break the chain.

**A little example**

```
// How you define a Title dependency property
public string Title
{ 
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); } 
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); } 
} 

public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CheckListItemControl), new PropertyMetadata("default title")); 

// How you bind the Title dp of the usercontrol to a TextBlock thru ElementName binding
<UserControl x:Name="MyCheckListItemControl" ... 
  // I assume you are using a TextBlock to display the Title
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=MyCheckListItemControl}" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time.I'm not sure what a DependencyProperty is,it looks kind of complicated and I got databinding working so far without using DependencyProperties so I'm not sure it's causing the problem.If I do this:<TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationName}"/> (outside UserControl,in page),it works fine.There's no use of DependancyProperties involved in that.Also,DataContext="this" is not set in the UserControl but in the PhoneApplicationPage's constructor.I'm not trying to bind Title of UserControl to TextBlock but PhoneApplicationPage.Applicationname to UserControl.Title.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationName}"/> works fine because Text is a dependency property. However Title="{Binding ApplicationName}" won't work because you defined the Title as a normal property. Yes, I understand that you are trying to bind the app name to your usercontrol's Title, but how would you display the Title on your usercontrol?

Comment: Xin is right, if you're adding new properties to a control, they should be Dependency Properties. The declaration is ugly, but once you create your first one it's mainly just copy/paste to create others, I don't memorize the format and just look for another I can copy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill and @Xin,I think I understand what you mean.I'll give it a try and let you know if the problem is solved.@Xin : I don't want to display title.I was only using it to keep my problem simple.What I'm trying to do is bind objects like for example a List<Person> which is stored in the isolatedstorage.By adding each Person to a Control I can associate userinteraction with a specific Control to a specific Person and incorporate logic around that Person in that Control opposed to handling it in page(<src:CheckListItemControl checkListItem="{Binding CheckListItem}"). Thanks again.

Comment: If this is the case then all you need is a do Title. ;)

Comment: Problem solved, it works now.  the funny thing is I read about DepedencyProperties in Charles Petzold's book before so I should have known, I guess.  But it just didn't sink in at the time.  Thanks for your time and input guys!